# Generated Splash Screens from react-native-bootsplash are too small

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, splash-screen, android-splashscreen

### Problem

We use [react-native-bootsplash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-bootsplash) to auto-generate our Splash Screens. The Problem is that even when using the `--logo-width=288` option (which is the max size), the generated images are still too small.

Is there a way to adjust them afterwards? I tried using the *Cordova* resource generator to adjust the files in *Android Studio*, but the generated files just crashed the app.

The problem is mainly with Android, the tools in iOS seem to be better.

Comment: I had some problem with it too, but I changed picture that I use. Try cropping everything besides the logo. Where did you find that 288 is the max size?

Comment: If you enter a size larger than 288 it will abort the process with the message that a higher size can lead to cropping on Android.